# JavaFX rectangle is overwriting border

Tags: javafx, border

Given:

```
package pkg;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStroke;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStrokeStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderWidths;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var scene = new Scene(getView(), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private Pane getView() {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 200);
        r.setFill(Color.RED);
        r.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
        r.setStrokeWidth(10);
        pane.getChildren().add(r);
        pane.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY,
                new BorderWidths(2))));
        AnchorPane ap = new AnchorPane();
        ap.getChildren().add(pane);
        return ap;
    }
}
```

This renders as:
[image]

Why is the rectangle stomping the border of its container? It appears the pane is sized to the size of the rectangle plus the stroke width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be the expected result of the "absolute positioning of children" offered by [`Pane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html), which "does not perform layout beyond resizing resizable children to their preferred sizes." In particular,

- The red rectangle's top left corner is at (0, 0).
- The [`strokeType`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#strokeTypeProperty) defaults to `CENTERED`, placing its top left corner at (0, 0), clipped to the left and above.
- The black border shows the computed size, absent any layout.

For comparison, the example below adds the rectangle and border to a  [`StackPane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html), which lays out its children with `Pos.CENTER` alignment by default.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStroke;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStrokeStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderWidths;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(getView()));
        stage.show();
    }

    private Pane getView() {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 200);
        r.setFill(Color.RED);
        r.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
        r.setStrokeWidth(10);
        StackPane sp = new StackPane();
        sp.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK,
            BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new BorderWidths(2))));
        sp.getChildren().add(r);
        return sp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this will do the trick, though I must say the original result is not intuitive, at least for me. My intuition and JavaFX are not congruent, as I run into things like this a lot.

Comment: It's an odyssey; for reference, I use [_Digital Color Meter_](https://support.apple.com/guide/digital-color-meter/welcome/mac) > View > Show Mouse Location to check position, geometry, color, aliasing, _etc_.